# adding or remove multiple classes with attributes.addClass

Tags: theming, 8

In my page template I can add a single class and remove a single class like this 
`<aside{{attributes.addClass(sidebar_first_classes).removeClass('content_classes') }}>` But now I want to add a single class and remove two classes, and this does not work
 `<asideright{{attributes.addClass(sidebar_second_classes).removeClass('content_classes','sidebar_first_classes') }}>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates) for addClass and removeClass:

> attributes.removeClass()
>
> Removes a class from an Attribute object. Used similarly to addClass.
>   Let's say you get the classes variable from somewhere else like a
>   preprocess function.
>
> {% set classes = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ] %}
>
> <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes).removeClass('green')
>   }}></div> outputs <div class="red blue"></div>.

So either you need to use an array to remove multiple classes or make multiple calls the removeClass and a single class.