# Twig attribues.addclass nesting issue

Tags: theming

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm on my first week working with drupal and twig.

I have the following code:

```
{%
  set container_classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished',
    'container'  
  ]  
%}
{% set image_classes = [
  'col-12'  
]
%}
{% block paragraph %}  
  
  {% block content %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(container_classes) }}>
      <div class='row'>
        <div{{ attributes.addClass(image_classes) }} data-type='image'>
          {{ content.field_two_column_image }}          
        </div>
        <div class='col-12 col-lg-auto' data-type='copy'>
          {{ content.field_two_column_copy }}
        </div>
      </div?>
    </div>          
  {% endblock %}
 
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

My issue is the nested attributes.addClass. When I look at the HTML, I'm also seeing the container_classes classes, which is not what I'm looking for.

So how can I separate the two?

Comment: `{{ attributes }}` is the same array as it is used through your file. When you `.addClass()` it is added to that array. If you have nested elements and apply that array you will need to `.removeClass()` if you don’t want particular classes to cascade to those child elements

Comment: So something like this

<div{{ attributes.addClass(container_classes).removeClass(container) }} data-type='image'>

and ensure all my classes are in the one array?

Comment: That syntax is correct. This DA might be helpful: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250300/adding-or-remove-multiple-classes-with-attributes-addclass. `@CamelCode` provides a really good option, though for certain nested elements it might make more sense to set classes manually with html than with the attributes array. e.g. `class=""` on the element. Really depends on if these classes will be reused or not, and if a new attribute array makes sense for your use case.

Comment: I would normally set them manually, but the component has options (image left or right) that I'm using to set a class. I don't build my prototypes with everything a parent class on the outer div, so i'll need to make some adjustments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attributes` is a variable containing attributes information (class, id, others..) for the main container of the template.
It should usually be used only once.

You can create a new attribute variable like this :

`{% set my_attribute = create_attribute() %}|`

And you can use it as usual :

```
<div{{ my_attribute.addClass(image_classes).setAttribute('data-type', 'image') }}>
  {{ content.field_two_column_image }}          
</div>
```

More information about using the `attributes` variable in Twig templates :
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8.2.x

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try that and see if I can get what I need to work. Classes would make it easier, but a data attribute might work too